# vba find if a user input value exist in excel sheet gets error if not found twice but ok when not found once

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below macro but the problem is I need to input many records and when value not found it gives the msgbox which is fine but if again a value not found the whole thing collapse and stop working.
Why first time value not found the program continues normally but if again a value not found it collapses?

```vb
Sub Macro4()

On Error GoTo errmsg

errmsg:

MsgBox "not found"

Do While MsgBox("Do you have after sales applications?", vbYesNo) = vbYes

    Cells.Find(What:=InputBox("Please input Full Account Number"), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _

        , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _

        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

    Selection.EntireRow.Select

    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Range("A1").Insert 

    Sheets("ELEC").Select

    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    On Error GoTo errmsg

Loop


        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

        Columns("R:R").Select

        Selection.Replace What:="N", Replacement:="R", LookAt:= _

        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _

        ReplaceFormat:=False

     finalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Range(Cells(1, "B"), Cells(finalRow, "B")).EntireRow.Select

    Selection.Cut

    Sheets("ELEC").Select

    Rows("7:7").Insert

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Improving Code: Message Box and Input Box in *Do...Loop*

- Usually, account numbers are in a single column so you should restrict the find to it with e.g. `sws.Columns("A").Find(...)`. Also, the significance of row `7` is unclear so maybe you need `sws.Range("A2:A6").Find(...)`. Be careful though, if you modify as suggested, `ActiveCell` will not work and you should use the last cell of the suggested range as the `After` argument's parameter.
- I think `ActiveCell` is a bad idea anyway because it is the only reason why I had to add the first two `If` statements.
- The source-destination logic is kind of compromised since in the 'bottom part' of the code you're moving from destination to source.

```vb
Sub MoveAccounts()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    If Not wb Is ActiveWorkbook Then wb.Activate

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("ELEC")
    If Not sws Is ActiveSheet Then sws.Select
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim scell As Range, AccountNumber As String, HasAccountMoved As Boolean
    
    Do While MsgBox("Do you have after sales applications?", _
            vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes
        
        AccountNumber = InputBox("Please input Full Account Number")
        
        Set scell = sws.Cells.Find(What:=AccountNumber, _
            After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
        
        If scell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Account number not found!", vbExclamation
        Else
            With scell.EntireRow
                .Copy
                dws.Range("A1").Insert
                .EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With
            HasAccountMoved = True
        End If
    
    Loop

    If Not HasAccountMoved Then Exit Sub
    
    dws.Columns("R").Replace What:="N", Replacement:="R", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    
    Dim drg As Range, dLastRow As Long
    
    dLastRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set drg = dws.Range(dws.Cells(1, "B"), dws.Cells(dLastRow, "B")).EntireRow

    drg.Cut
    sws.Rows(7).Insert

End Sub
```